# Append counted value for a list of values

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.6

The following program works exactly as intended:

```
destinations = {}
while True:
    query = input("Tell me where you went: ").strip()
    if not query:
        break
    if query.count(',') != 1:
        print("That's not a legal city, state combination. Please try again.\n")
        continue

    city, country = query.split(',')
    city = city.strip()
    country = country.strip()

    if country not in destinations:
        destinations[country] = [city]
    else:
        destinations[country].append(city)

temp1 = {key: sorted(destinations[key]) for key in destinations.keys()}
temp2 = {key: value for key, value in sorted(temp1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])}

# temp2 = {}
# for key in sorted(temp1.keys()):
#     temp2[key] = temp1[key]

for key, value in temp2.items():
    print(key)
    for elem in value:
        print('\t' + elem)
```

Sample:

```
Tell me where you went: Shanghai, China
Tell me where you went: Boston, USA
Tell me where you went: Beijing, China
Tell me where you went: London, England
Tell me where you went: Phoenix, USA
Tell me where you went: Hunan, China
Tell me where you went: Denver, USA
Tell me where you went: Moscow, USSR
Tell me where you went: Leningrad, USSR
Tell me where you went: San Francisco, USA
Tell me where you went: Indianapolis, USA
Tell me where you went: Jakarta, Phillipines
Tell me where you went: 
China
    Beijing
    Hunan
    Shanghai
England
    London
Phillipines
    Jakarta
USA
    Boston
    Denver
    Indianapolis
    Phoenix
    San Francisco
USSR
    Leningrad
    Moscow
```

There is one aspect I do not like, and that is how it handles duplicates city, country entries.

I am trying to modify my code so that if a city, country pair is entered that already exists then the output would look like this:

```
China
    Beijing (2)
    Shanghai
England
    London
USA
    Boston
    Chicago (2)
    New York
```

I thought that a good idea was to change my list of values to a list of lists
like this:

```
    if country not in destinations:
        destinations[country] = [[city]]
    else:
        destinations[country].append([city])
```

Then I thought I would check to see if the city already existed and if it did
I would append to the embedded list a value for that city starting with 2:

destinations = {'England': [['Birmingham', 2], ['London'], ['Wiltshire', 3]]}

I can't get it to work.  Maybe there is a better way to represent multiple occurrences of a given city, country pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good effort.  You can simply replace your last `for` loop with this:

**Code**

```
import collections as ct


for country, cities in temp2.items():
    counter = ct.Counter(cities)
    seen = set()
    print(country)
    for city in cities:
        count = counter[city]
        if city not in seen and count > 1:
            print("\t {:<20} ({})".format(city, count))        # new format
        elif city not in seen:
            print("\t {}".format(city))                        # old format
        seen.add(city)
```

Here we use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to track repeated cities.  As we iterate the cities for a given country, any repeated cities are printed in your desired [format](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3), otherwise the old format is used.  To avoid printing cities again, every city is added to a set which is searched prior to printing.

---

**Suggestions**

To clean up your code, consider refactoring it by making two functions.

```
def get_destinations():
    """Return a dictionary of destinations from the user."""
    destinations = ct.defaultdict(list)
    while True:

        # INSERT INPUT LOGIC HERE

        destinations[country].append(city)
    return destinations


def print_destinations(destinations):
    """Print city and countries."""
    temp1 = {k: sorted(v) for k, v in destinations.items()}
    temp2 = {k: v for k, v in sorted(temp1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])}

    # Python < 3.6, optional
    # temp2 = ct.OrderedDict()
    # for k, v in sorted(temp1.items()):
    #     temp2[k] = v

    # INSERT POSTED CODE HERE
```

**Demo**

```
>>> dest = get_destinations()
>>> dest
Tell me where you went: Beijing, China
Tell me where you went: Atlanta, USA
Tell me where you went: Beijing, China
Tell me where you went: New York, USA
Tell me where you went: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'China': ['Beijing', 'Beijing'], 'USA': ['Atlanta', 'New York']})

>>> print_destinations(dest)
China
     Beijing              (2)
USA
     Atlanta
     New York
```

---

**Details**

In `get_destinations()`, we refactor by:

- using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which sets an empty list as a default value.
- returning the default dictionary; note repeated cities are retained.

In `print_destinations()`, we refactor by:

- sorting keys directly (no need for `.keys()`) and sorting the values of `temp1`
- leverage [preserved key insertion in Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/) to maintain an alphabetized dictionary; note for any lesser version of Python, the [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) should be used (commented code)